# Bootstrap Column Overlap Before Breakpoint

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

When collapsing the window before it hits the medium breakpoint, the column containing the select field overlaps the first column with the "heading". Not sure why. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]
[image]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <span class="h2">Leads</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <form>
      <input type="hidden" name="status" id="status" value="Today">
      <input type="hidden" name="tab" id="tab-status-agent" value="follow_up">
      <select name="user_id" id="select-agent" class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="">All Team Members</option>
        <option value="unassigned">Unassigned</option>
        <option value="7">Luke Skywalker</option>
        <option value="2">Han Solo</option>
        <option value="1">Leia Organa</option>
      </select>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5 text-right">
    <form data-remote="false" class="d-inline" id="power-dialer-form" action="/calls/power_dialer" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="vqtLpEeM2kh5MP7nZFhFrfrmJhjm6T3IF++8UGmHpHjZP4E9WSOpIsextGJptcRYPIuDBqVWgDkVYeHOn9uWow==">
      <button type="submit" name="commit" value="" class="btn btn-primary" id="add-to-power-dialer" disabled="">
      <i class="fas fa-phone" title="Add to power dialer"></i>
      </button>
    </form>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#assign-leads" title="Assign leads" href="#">
      <span class="fas fa-user-check"></span>
      </a>    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#new-lead" title="New lead" href="#">
      <span class="fas fa-user-plus"></span>
      </a>    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#import-leads" title="Import leads" href="#">
      <span class="fas fa-file-import"></span>
      </a>  
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="input-group search-bar">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <div class="input-group-text" id="btnGroupAddon"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></div>
      </div>
      <input type="search" id="search" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I attempted this setting:

```
ROW: COL-2 COL-3 COL-4 COL-3
```

Which fixes the overlap but then the select field is too far away from the heading.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code i hope it will be worked

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <span class="h2">Leads</span>
    <form class="ml-3">
      <input type="hidden" name="status" id="status" value="Today">
      <input type="hidden" name="tab" id="tab-status-agent" value="follow_up">
      <select name="user_id" id="select-agent" class="form-control" 
       onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="">All Team Members</option>
        <option value="unassigned">Unassigned</option>
        <option value="7">Luke Skywalker</option>
        <option value="2">Han Solo</option>
        <option value="1">Leia Organa</option>
      </select>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5 text-right">
    <form data-remote="false" class="d-inline" id="power-dialer-form" action="/calls/power_dialer" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="vqtLpEeM2kh5MP7nZFhFrfrmJhjm6T3IF++8UGmHpHjZP4E9WSOpIsextGJptcRYPIuDBqVWgDkVYeHOn9uWow==">
      <button type="submit" name="commit" value="" class="btn btn-primary" id="add-to-power-dialer" disabled="">
      <i class="fas fa-phone" title="Add to power dialer"></i>
      </button>
    </form>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#assign-leads" title="Assign leads" href="#">
      <span class="fas fa-user-check"></span>
      </a>    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#new-lead" title="New lead" href="#">
      <span class="fas fa-user-plus"></span>
      </a>    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#import-leads" title="Import leads" href="#">
      <span class="fas fa-file-import"></span>
      </a>  
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="input-group search-bar">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <div class="input-group-text" id="btnGroupAddon"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></div>
      </div>
      <input type="search" id="search" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not work. The select field is now located under the heading as they now sharing one column with the default `.col` style of `display: block`